# On Click Color Changer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a color changer for background and font colors. It is working for the most part, but I am unable to figure out how to get the links and the h2/h3 tags to change with the rest of the text.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('ColorChanger');
var allColors = [];
var currentColor = 0;

allColors.push({bg:"black",front:"#5DBF1B"});
allColors.push({bg:"#89a7e2",front:"black"});
allColors.push({bg:"black",front:"white"});
allColors.push({bg:"white",front:"black"});

div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var self = this,
        old_bg = this.style.background;

    document.body.style.background = allColors[currentColor].bg;
    document.body.style.color = allColors[currentColor].front;

   currentColor++;
if(currentColor == allColors.length) currentColor = 0;

})
```

```html
<div id="ColorChanger"><img alt="Click to change color" class="ignore_menu_hide" src="/App_Themes/Site/assets/images/theme_icon.png" /></div>




           <h2>Follow Us</h2>
<ul class="social_media"><li><a href="#" alt="Facebook Link">

Facebook</a></li>
<li><a href="#" alt="Twitter Link">

Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href="#" alt="">
RSS Feeds</a></li>
<li><a href="#">
YouTube</a></li>
<li><a href="#" alt="Linked In Link">
LinkedIn</a></li>
<li><a href="#" alt="Pinterest Link">
Pinterest</a></li>
<li><a href="#" alt="">

Instagram</a></li>
 </ul>


<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Comment: make use of the `!important` rule in CSS, and it will overwrite the default colors

Comment: Use the chrome dev tools to help diagnose css issues. Press ctrl+shift+i to open it, and navigate to the consoles tab. You can highlight and element and see it's css rules. If they are not there, you know there is an issue with your code. If they are there but are crossed out with a black line then you know there is an issue with the css being overwritten. I am not a big fan of css and I could not get by without this utility.

Comment: @N.Ivanov That would work if he set classes to elements, but he is dynamically applying styling on click, not adding actual classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to grab those elements using `document.getElementsByTagName("p")`/ `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")` / `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` iterate them and apply the styling.

```
var div = document.getElementById('ColorChanger');
var allColors = [];
var currentColor = 0;

allColors.push({
    bg: "black",
    front: "#5DBF1B"
});
allColors.push({
    bg: "#89a7e2",
    front: "black"
});
allColors.push({
    bg: "black",
    front: "white"
});
allColors.push({
    bg: "white",
    front: "black"
});

div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var self = this,
        old_bg = this.style.background;

    document.body.style.background = allColors[currentColor].bg;
    document.body.style.color = allColors[currentColor].front;

    var pElements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var h2Elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
    var aElements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (var i = 0; i < pElements.length; i++) {
        pElements[i].style.color = allColors[currentColor].front;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < h2Elements.length; i++) {
        h2Elements[i].style.color = allColors[currentColor].front;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++) {
        aElements[i].style.color = allColors[currentColor].front;
    }

    currentColor++;
    if (currentColor == allColors.length) currentColor = 0;

})
```